# Force page to refresh after user clicks a form button

Tags: php

I have a user button that deletes a post when the click it using the below code. However, the user has to refresh the page to see that the post has been deleted. Is there a way to force the page to refresh when the user clicks the delete button WITHOUT using the header approach? I am using WordPress and the headers are already sent through the template and if I try header(javascript code) I get an error that headers are already sent.

```
if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
$the_WID = $_POST['remove'];


$dlt = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE post.WID = :postWID";
$stmtdlt = $dbh->prepare($dlt);
$stmtdlt->bindParam(':postWID', $the_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);                                           
$stmtdlt->execute(); 



<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
<input type="hidden" name="remove" value="<?php echo $resulting[post]; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: JavaScript has a reload() function that reloads the current document. You could set the header to header('Location: http://www.example.com") or even make use of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can use header in php

example:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

refer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I should have specified that I was looking for another way that does not involve headers. The problem is that I am using WordPress and headers are already sent through the template so I can't use this approach

Comment: You can go with java script to reload the page forcefully.

Comment: So i could add some javascript code at the end of the IF statement so the query runs first after the button is clicked and then refreshes?

Comment: you can do like function call on delete. And in that function u can do ajax call according to response you can do force refresh the page.